# Возможные перестановки по длине

Tags: java

У меня есть какой то массив со словами, который я сортирую по длине. Хочу сделать так, что бы на выходе он выдавал все возможные перестановки. Что я имею ввиду:

```
1) Дано String[] tst = {"H","G","HHHhh","HGFD"}
2) Что могу пока = {"H","G","HGFD","HHHhh"} - сортировка по длине
3) Хочу получить = {"H","G","HGFD","HHHhh"} - Первый ответ
                 = {"G","H","HGFD","HHHhh"} - Второй ответ
```

Как мне лучше подойти к этой проблеме ? С чего начать ?

```
public class Tetst {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] strArray = {"Agar", "Hefo", "Baraa", "aaa", "baaalbal"};

        for(int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < strArray.length - 1 - i; j++){
                if(strArray[j].length() > strArray[j + 1].length()){
                    String str = strArray[j];
                    strArray[j] = strArray[j + 1];
                    strArray[j + 1] = str;
                }
            }
        }

        for(String s : strArray){
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начните с подхода в лоб. У вас есть N элементов. Это значит на первом месте у вас может быть любой из них. На втором - любой из них, кроме того, что сейчас стоит на первом месте. На третьем любой из них, кроме двух, которые попали на 1 и 2 место. Первое что просится - рекурсивная функция. Она принимает в себя набор всех значений и текущий набор, длинной меньше или равной общему.

```
f(all, current){
    if(all.size == current.size){
        print(current);
        return;
    } 
    for(o in all){
        current.add(o);
        f(all.current);
        current.remove(o);
    }
}
```

Раз уж вы ставите вопрос "с чего начать" - предположу что вы хотите все же сами решить задачу, потому остановлюсь на этом недоалгоритме на недоязыке. Оставлю вам на подумать вопросы допустимости прибавления o к current, запуска алгоритма, сохранения результатов и еще чего-нибудь